# High Score recall not working Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults, sprite-kit

i am creating an iOS simple game and i have a int variable called scorescore that gets the score every time you play the game. I have made an int variable called highscore and stored it using NSUserDefaults and this always works the first time it can never recall it after that for some reason

e.g. i play the game for the first time an get a highscore of 2 and it stores the highscore of two and all is good. but then if i get above two in my next go it won't change the high-score.

```
 int highscoreyeah = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"HIGHSCOREppp"] integerValue];

    if (scorescore >> highscoreyeah) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:scorescore] forKey:@"HIGHSCOREppp"];
    }

    int highscoreshowm = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"HIGHSCOREppp"] integerValue];
```

I am using sprite kit by the way, dunno if this makes a difference...

Comment: Andrey has a point there with his answer. Also you should not forget to `synchronize` the `userdefaults` after writing them... `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
if (scorescore >> highscoreyeah)
```

to

```
if (scorescore > highscoreyeah)
```

`>>` is a Bitwise Operator, not Equality Operator (very different things)